# How to put tab within code section?

Tags: support, code-formatting, tabs

How could I put <kbd>Tab</kbd> in order to format the code ? (same as press 4 time "space") 
For example in the follow pic I want the put tab in the 2nd line (the 1st line made by spaces)-

[image]

Comment: [Better handling of indentation and the TAB key when editing posts](http://stackapps.com/q/3247)

Comment: You want to put a tab character inside your `inline code block`?

Comment: @DannyBeckett : Does it available in chrome ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `spaces`     in inline code, but AFAIK the only way to do this is with manual HTML. The spaces will be stripped out if you use Markdown like `this`.

Markdown:

```
You can have <code>spaces&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</code> in inline code,
but AFAIK the only way to do this is with manual HTML. The spaces will
be stripped out if you use Markdown like `     this      `.
```

There's no such thing as a "tab" in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Put four spaces in the beginning of the line then tabs are preserved:

```
hello       world
```

As for plain text, you can use four `&nbsp;` to emulate tab:

hello          world

Comment: They're only preserved in the answer _source_, the displayed result still shows 4 spaces per tab :(

Comment: @MestreLion true. It's impossible to have actual tab character there anyway, what we do instead is put spaces. That's just how things work, ever did and probably will always be this way.